# How to make a line graph in android studio in kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, charts, linechart

I am making an android application in the valley and I want to make a line graph but nowhere can I find the correct documentation and there are always errors. Someone will either give the correct version or show the correct code

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YHRPz.png)

Comment: share code. Not only the problem

Comment: look to code. I edited the post in the post is code

Comment: which library are you using to create your chart?

Comment: I'm using MPAndroidChart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Explay how you can do it from more or less 30 code lines it's hard. But I can suggest you to search how to implement it searching an article. Click [here](https://medium.com/@yilmazvolkan/kotlinlinecharts-c2a730226ff1) and follow the article.
I hope can help you :-)

### Edit

to solve `lineChart` error, declare it as below:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)


        var lineChart: LineChart
}
```

Make sure to import:

```
import com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart
```

if you have problem to find the import go to app `build.gradle` and paste it:

```
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }

}
```

and:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

### Edit 2

If you want to follow the link example, lineGraph must be declared. In this case, linegraph is nothing more than the id of the object declared in the `activity_layout.xml`. In fact you will need to add this piece of code in your `activity_layout.xml`:

```
<com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart
    android:id="@+id/lineChart"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
    android:padding="9dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Once added you will have to go to the mainactivity and in the onCreate write:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
   
              val lineChart = findViewById<LineChart>(R.id.lineChart)
    }
```

To solve the other two problems, just read the article to the end. In fact, CustomMarker is a class defined as follows:

```
class CustomMarker(context: Context, layoutResource: Int):  MarkerView(context, layoutResource) {
    override fun refreshContent(entry: Entry?, highlight: Highlight?) {
        val value = entry?.y?.toDouble() ?: 0.0
        var resText = ""
        if(value.toString().length > 8){
            resText = "Val: " + value.toString().substring(0,7)
        }
        else{
            resText = "Val: " + value.toString()
        }
        tvPrice.text = resText
        super.refreshContent(entry, highlight)
    }

    override fun getOffsetForDrawingAtPoint(xpos: Float, ypos: Float): MPPointF {
        return MPPointF(-width / 2f, -height - 10f)
    }
}
```

Comment: I have problem , look in the post is photo

Comment: Either your code isn't complete or you haven't declared some variables. the errors in the photos have nothing to do with the code you posted. In the photo you have a ShowForexActivity, while in the code you posted you have a MainActivity. Are you getting the code from another project by any chance?

Comment: the code is definitely complete, how do i declare the variables?

Comment: I added a picture to the post of my entire screen

Comment: I don't know what I'm doing wrong

Comment: see my edit tips

Comment: so, don't miss to replace  ShowForexActivity with MainActivity :-)

Comment: It's almost ok, but I still have a problem with what is marked in the photo

Comment: I think I've explained everything to you. What you need is to keep reading the article, understand what the library does and then apply it to your project. If my comments were helpful don't forget to confirm it :-)

Comment: I still have a problem with "j" from the previous photo and a problem with "tvPena" with the next photo

Comment: do you know what could be the reason?

Comment: I've already found all the bugs except one "j" I don't know what to do with it

Comment: you have an idea how to solve the problem with "j"

Comment: it's just a variable. Replace it with a number and try it

Comment: I have one more question, because when I run the application on the phone, after pressing the graph, the application crashes

Comment: It's correct accept this answer and open new question about crash :-)

Comment: @MaksChojniak mark this answer as correct if helped you